# What is this written on several buildings in red paint?

Tags: translation

Walking down the street in Tianjin I see this:

[image: written on building walls in red paint]

My question is: what does it say, and what does it mean?

It's written in red paint on several buildings that I walk past.  The same thing is written maybe 4 or 5 times.

I tried to translate it using [search by radical](http://www.chinese-tools.com/tools/sinograms.html?r) and [handwriting recognition](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/chinese_handwriting_recognition/chinese_handwriting_recognition.php), and this is all I managed:

```
外?空裂
请勿停?
注意安全
```

It says something about mind your safety, and don't park here (?).  I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

外檐空裂

请勿停靠

注意安全

“ the outer eaves are missing and broken

please not park alongside

watch out for safety”